# How can I generate marquee using CSS3 in HTML5

Tags: html, css, frontend

My HTML code is

```
  <div class="container1">
   <div id="container-table"></div>
   <div id="container-tablec"></div>
   <div id="container-tableq"></div>
   <div id="container-table"></div>
   <div id="container-table"></div>
  </div>
```

Now, each of these **DIVs generates a widget** (similar to the one in stock markets). I want to add all of these in a **marquee effect** which runs endlessly and there is no gap between the last div and the div of the next loop.

I'm a newbie to web development. I've tried using  tag but, there is a gap between the ending of the last div and the beginning of the next loop. Also, **MDN** suggests that I should not use it as it is an **obsolete** feature.

I want to give it a look similar to the one in stock markets where the entire loop id endless and runs infinitely.

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve this using CSS3.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: all running in one line from right to left or 5 running from left to right?

Comment: I know you asked for suggestions but, unfortunately, new people will instead write code for you which is off topic here including the opinions of how it should be done. We can help with markup and code you wrote but we cannot write code for you and their responses will get this question closed.

Comment: all running in one line from right to left infinitely without any break after the first loop with 5 has finished the second should start immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you

```css
/* Sets up our marquee, and inner content */
.marquee {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 100%;
  /* Some browsers may require -webkit-animation */
  animation: reduce 20s linear infinite;
}

.marquee__inner {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  /* Some browsers may require -webkit-animation */
  animation: scroll 20s linear infinite;
}


/* Creates two white-to-transparent gradients at the ends of the marquee */
.marquee::before,
.marquee::after {
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.marquee::after {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

@keyframes reduce {
  to {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes scroll {
  to {
    transform: translateX( -100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  <span class="marquee__inner">some text .</span>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Rubhan/qq7o8qoh/)